# i have a gap when trying to center the pseudo element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

i have a `button` and i try to add a `::before` pseudo element to it in the center
but when i trying i get a small gap i can't remove

i use **FireFox** and this is the result when run the code

> note:
>
> - i need the `::before` to be centered by `position: absolute;`
> - in the real code the square is not 100% of the button but 50% . i made it like that to make the error clear
> - i don't need to fill the square using the `::before` but center it because in the real code it is a just a 50% of the area

[image]

it shouldn't have a white pixels

```css
body { 
    background: #111;
}

button {
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #07f;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}

button::before { 
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(0, 209, 105);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    translate: -50% -50%;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: The problem is when the button size is an odd number then 50% of it contains 0.5 pixels but CSS does not support fractions of pixels

Answer (score 0):

Add 1px to `button::before` and set `button { overflow: hidden; }`:

```css
body { 
  background: #111;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #07f;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  overflow:hidden;
}

button::before { 
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% + 1px);
  height: calc(100% + 1px);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  translate:-50% -50%;
  background: rgb(0, 209, 105);
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: this is a way to make the error clear
but in the real app it isn't a 100% 100%

Comment: thanks for your answer 
but i can't do that in the real code i have a circle that is less than a half for the button and i need to center it not to make it fill the button

Comment: There are 2 action options in the answer. Have you checked the second option?

Comment: yes, my problem with it is that in my real code the square is just a 50% of the button 
i made it 100% so the white space can be clear

Comment: Please specify all the nuances in the question so as not to waste time...

Comment: i'm sorry. i edited it after i read your answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the button size is an odd number then 50% of it contains 0.5 pixels but CSS does not support fractions of pixels